# Better way to array_merge in php?

Tags: php, array-merge

I created this working code using array_merge in php.

getData() is returning an array.

```
    $cars = array();


    $cars = array_merge($cars, $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 0, -1));
    $cars = array_merge($cars, $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, -1));
    $cars = array_merge($cars, $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, 0));
    $cars = array_merge($cars, $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, 1));
```

There is a better way to do the same?

Comment: well for starters array_merge can take more than two arguments. the rest depends on what you have in getData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) accepts multiple arguments:

```
$cars = array_merge($this->getData($x, $y, $z, 0, -1),
                    $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, -1),
                    $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, 0),
                    $this->getData($x, $y, $z, 1, 1));
```